# Postgres time 00 and 24 hours

Tags: postgresql

Why the following query return `false`?

```
SELECT ('00:00:00'::TIME) = ('24:00:00'::TIME) AS "time", ('00:00:00'::TIMETZ) = ('24:00:00'::TIMETZ) AS "timetz"
```

**Result:**

```
+-------+--------+
| time  | timetz |
+-------+--------+
| false | false  |
+-------+--------+
```

While the result of the following query is same!!

```sql
SELECT ('00:00:00'::TIME) AS "time1", ('24:00:00'::TIME) AS "time2", ('00:00:00'::TIMETZ) AS "timetz1" , ('24:00:00'::TIMETZ) AS "timetz2"
```

**Result:**

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+
|  time1   |  time2   |        timetz1         |        timetz2         |
+----------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 |
+----------+----------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

What is difference between `00:00:00` and `24:00:00` in postgres?

Comment: Just a guess, but you *may* be stuck on a Postgres version `<= 8.0.x`, aren't you? And the documentation you are reading is for a newer version? Value ranges of `time` and `timetz` have been slightly increased from `8.0` to `8.1`.

Comment: Which tool are you using? [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4a1146198f8b5d738f2e1e26f08e85cc)  shows 00 and 24 (and so does `psql` and my JDBC based query tool)

Comment: I am using postgres 12 and data grip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres' `time` type is defined to have a range of `'00:00:00'` to `'24:00:00'`, inclusive on both ends.  To see why the two endpoints are not the same, consider:

```
SELECT '00:00:00'::time AS start, '24:00:00'::time AS end;
```

For the end value, I see `1.00:00:00`, contrary to what you see, indicating that 24 hours is actually one day, with zero hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: I think this depends on the SQL client. e.g. `psql` will display `00:00:00 | 24:00:00` (and so does [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2fb8a756ac0a4f78e640619b0923d802)). My JDBC based query tool displays `00:00:00 | 00:00:00`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes...the OP's second output may be an artifact, and could be misleading.